# Change UIButton textLabel position when UIScrollView scrolls button outside of visible view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, uilabel

I have an interesting scenario that I'm kind of stuck with ideas on.  I'm hoping that someone knows of a "UIButton+FloatingLabel" category of some sort, or maybe just something easy I'm overlooking.

I have a horizontally scrolling UIScrollView with a bunch of buttons of various widths.  The problem I'm facing is that when a UIButton starts to scroll outside of the visible view, the textLabel goes along with it (the label is leftAligned in the button).

I want to be able to detect this and keep the label "floating" inside the remaining button's view until the whole button scrolls away.

The closest thing I can think of is to override the UIScrollView `layoutSubviews` and check the labels view with each contentOffset update, but this can be quite costly with a lot of buttons.

Can anyone offer some guidance or a couple useful links? Any help appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

one way this could be implemented is to subclass `UIButton` and use your own label in that subclass. Then override the `drawRect:` method of your custom `UIButton` to change the position of the label based on the button's position on the physical screen ( `[UIScreen mainScreen]` ).

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but `drawRect` only gets called once (when the button gets displayed).  I could start spamming `setNeedsDisplay`, but I think that will just as inefficient as the `layoutSubviews` method I described above.

Comment: yes that is true. I dont see any other way that is not exhaustive. I say give either of them a try and see how they perform, you never know!

Comment: if you think about it, you only need to call `setNeedsDisplay` to the buttons that are crossing the edges of the screen, which im assuming, are not too many of them at any given time?

Comment: I could do a check to see if the `x` or `x+width` coordinates of each UIButton are outside the frame of the UIScrollView and call it then.  My main concern is that I'm trying to keep this to a minimum to ensure smooth scrolling.  I'll give it a shot and max out the UIButton loading to see what happens.